# How can I copy a tweet into python and print it out?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to copy text in a tweet from Twitter and then assign it to the word "tweet" to then modify it

Comment: are you asking about how to use the twitter api, or just how to create a string?

Comment: If it is the former, there are many guides that would help you do that online. This is the first that comes up on Google: https://medium.com/@jayeshsrivastava470/how-to-extract-tweets-from-twitter-in-python-47dd07f4e8e7.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem and what you did try before posting. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a string, you just need to write the text in quotation marks and assign it to the variable tweet. You assign a string to a variable by using the equal sign followed by the text in quotation marks. You can do that like this:

```
tweet = "text from twitter"
```